# Detecting activity creation for onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity

How to detect if an activity is started to handle onActivityResult or was started to just recreate the activity due to orientation change or other event.

I start activity A and if a condition is meet, I start activity B for which I handle the result in A.

In low memory situations the activity A is destroyed and recreated to handle result from B. 
During the onInit, my internal state shows that I still need to display activity B, and thus B is re-displayed.

How could I handle this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to try to address actual question being asked.**

In order to prevent running setup code when returning to an activity, you can take advantage of the `onSaveInstanceState` method. You can override this method in class `A` such that if your activity is killed, for whatever reason, you can store state about it (such as the fact you've already started activity `B` for a result). In this method, you modify the passed in `Bundle` by setting key value pairs on it. This bundle will then get passed to the class's `onCreate` when the activity is restarted. Thus the relevant parts of your class A might look like the following:

```
public class A extends Activity {
    boolean startedB = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        startedB = savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("started_b", false);
        if (!startedB) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            startedB = true;
        }
        // rest of code
        // .....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean("started_b", startedB);
    }
}
```

**Original Answer**

When you're starting an activity for a result, you can put an extra flag or value on the intent used to start the activity. For instance, if I want to start activity `Foo` for a result, I could use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Foo.class);
intent.putExtra(IS_FOR_RESULT, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

where `IS_FOR_RESULT` is a string such as `"IS_FOR_RESULT"` and `REQUEST_CODE` is an integer such as `1`. In the started activity's `onCreate` (in this case for the class `Foo`) you can check whether or not it was started for a result with the following

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra(IS_FOR_RESULT) && intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_FOR_RESULT) {
    // Handle activity being started for a result
}
```

Based on what you said, you may also want to have a similar check in the started class's `onNewIntent` in case you're starting an existing activity for a result and it doesn't create a new instance of it.

In general, [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) and intent extras are useful tools for passing instance specific information between application components.

Comment: Your suggestion is referring to class B, were I already use this mechanism to retrieve the intent options form A. My problem is that when the activity B is finished, activity A object is recreated onCreate and then onActivityResult invoked. During the onCreate I'm unable to detect if I still need to start activity B or not (e.g. the user dismissed, answerered)

Comment: Ah sorry, I hadn't understood. I've updated my answer, does it better address your question?

Comment: Yes, I did a try and actually seems to handle all (flip, startover, etc.) cases that I tested so far. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether the Activity has been started for result **within your application only**, by implementing logic suggested by [FuegoFro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766718/detecting-activity-creation-for-onactivityresult/20768313#20768313). However, you cannot detect in what way your Activity has been started from other apps.
It can be inferred from Android source codes: the only difference between starting Activity for result and just starting it is the value of `requestCode`:

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, -1);
}
```

and this `requestCode` is unrechable from the your Activity.